# System.OutOfMemoryException on loading files loop

Tags: out-of-memory, arrays, filestream

I have an application which writes files into DB (in addition to some basic info). The file is loaded into byte[] which is a part of a class I created, and then I run the query which insert the data to my table.

I have a foreach loop, and in the beginning I clear the byte[].

Many of my files fails due to: System.OutOfMemoryException. The largest file I have is 100MB.
I use Win7, 64bit, 4GB RAM
I also tried on Windows Server 2008 R2, 64bit, 16GB RAM
Both had many errors...

Here's the function which gets the file:

```
private byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileLength))
            {
                fileLength = "First file: " + stream.Length.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                fileLength += ", Second File:" + stream.Length.ToString();
            }

            ImageData = new byte[stream.Length];

            stream.Read(ImageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));

            stream.Close();

            return ImageData;
        }
    }
```

The `ImageData` is defined in the beginning of my code (outside of the loop):

```
byte[] ImageData = new byte[1];
```

My foreach loop looks something like that:

```
try
        {     

    // Setting basic info to MyEnt

            if (File.Exists(attachedFilesPath + doc.ScannedFileName))
            {
                 MyEnt.File = StreamFile(attachedFilesPath + doc.ScannedFileName);

                 MyEnt.MimeType = Helpers.GetMimeType(ext);
                 MyEnt.FileName = doc.Code + "-" + doc.Version + "." + ext;

                 ImageData = null;
    }                            

    // Setting basic info to MyEnt

            GC.Collect();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex
        }
```

**Note:** It seems my problem is that the memory won't be cleared...

What am I missing??

Comment: What language is this? I guess it's C#. I would try to use a memory analyzer to see where the memory is held.

Comment: Yes, it's C#... Could you recommend a memory analyzer tool for me (a free one...)?